# PHP preg match - get all valid group tags

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

For example, I have this string:

```
{% if test %}
   random text here
   {% case item %}{% when "hello" %}hi{% else %}goodbye{% endcase %}
   {% if hello %}text here{% else %}new text{% endif %}
random text here
{% endif %}
{% case item %}{% when "hello" %}hi{% else %}goodbye{% endcase %}
```

then with "preg_match_all", I'll get this result:

```
[0] => "{% if test %}random text here{% case item %}{% when "hello" %}hi{% else %}goodbye{% endcase %}{% if hello %}text here{% else %}new text{% endif %}random text here{% endif %}"
[1] => "{% case item %}{% when "hello" %}hi{% else %}goodbye{% endcase %}"
```

Basically, I just want to get group of tags. I tried different combination in regex but I can't the the right one.

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), use [an xml extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

Comment: got it. allow me to change the question as I will be using it in a different scenario too.

Comment: Let me be more clear. If you want to parse a markup language, don't consider using regex, write a parser. You can look at the other answers in the first link, they should tell you why not. Unless the string you want to parse is extremely specific, for instance `"/{% div %}.*{% enddiv %}|{% span %}.*{% endspan %}/"` can solve your question, but I don't think this is the solution you need.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're using PHP, you may try this regex using recursion `(?R)`:

```
\{%\s*(\w+)\b(?:(?!%}).)*%}(?:(?!\{%)[\s\S]|(?R))*?{%\s*end\1\s*%}
```

It makes sure it only captures the outer-most, balanced, and enclosed tags, here's the test case: https://regex101.com/r/3JbMQC/1